# XML to JSON works in firefox but produces TypeError in chrome

Tags: javascript, xml, json, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Im porting a browser extension from FF to chrome. I have this XMLHttpRequest, which works fine:

```
var xhrdata = new XMLHttpRequest(),

xhrdata.onreadystatechange = function () {               
    if (xhrdata.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhrdata.status === 200) {                
            getJXONTree(xhrdata.responseXML);                
        }
    }
};
xhrdata.open("GET", "mydomain.com/my.xml", true);
xhrdata.responseType = "document";
xhrdata.send();
```

This send the .responseXML over to this function (shortened)

```
function getJXONTree(oXMLParent) {
  var vResult = true, nLength = 0, sCollectedTxt = '';
  if (oXMLParent.hasAttributes()) {
    vResult = {};
    [...]
```

This works absolutely fine in firefox, but in chrome, polling the exact same XML with the exact same code, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Document> has no method 'hasAttributes'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: make sure you use the right content type

Comment: A document can't have any attributes. Firefox is wrong at this point. You need to use `hasAttributes` on a node, e.g. by using `getJXONTree(xhrdata.responseXML.documentElement);`

Comment: @robW jep that was right, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox is more lenient when it comes to this, but it has to be:

```
xhr.responseXML.documentElement
```

since documents dont have any attributes. thanks @robW